# What would happen if I pass an empty string to puts() in C?

Tags: c99

Does the C99 standard define the behaviour for:

`puts(s);// s != NULL but *s==""`

I had looked this up in the Linux manpages, but found nothing useful. Can someone please clarify?

Comment: Could you clearly ask the question instead of putting the full question in the title. I have no idea what your question means.

Comment: What do you mean? Could you clarify?

Comment: C99 does not define any garbage such as  this...

Comment: Why do you expect a valid empty string to be treated specially?

Comment: @Antonijn How about now ? ^_^

Comment: I reverted my down-vote and voted for reopening. The question looks fine now.

Comment: @Mat just curious about it :D

Comment: @Jinxiao Reverted the downvote  , next time try not to be such a quickdraw , when posting questions !!

Comment: @Jinxiao Actually, it's still not quite clear. And have you tried it? You should be able to just compile it and check it yourself.

Comment: @BarathBushan ok,i will.

Comment: @meh it's difficult to be a green hand :D

Comment: @Antonijn in general, "compile and check yourself" is not a very good solution for a standard based question - think about undefined or implementation-defined behaviours

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is what C99 says about `puts`:

> #### 7.19.7.10 The `puts` function
>
> **Synopsis**
>
> ```
> #include <stdio.h>
> int puts(const char *s);
> ```
>
> **Description**
>
> The puts function writes the string pointed to by `s` to the stream pointed to by `stdout`, and appends a new-line character to the output. The terminating null character is not written.
>
> **Returns**
>
> The puts function returns EOF if a write error occurs; otherwise it returns a nonnegative    value.

There is no mention of `s != NULL` or `*s==""`. Not to mention `*s==""` doesn't even make sense and you probably meant `*s == '\0'`.

---

> What would happen if I pass an empty string to puts() in C?

As the standard says:

> The puts function writes the string ...,
>       and appends a new-line character to the output.

So first the empty string is printed, i.e. nothing is printed, and then a new-line is printed. It effectively gets the cursor to the next line.